# Convert Geographic Time Format to HH:MM:SS

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am fairly new to VBA,

I have this specific time format looking like this:

```
1H 23’ 45,67”
```

Which translates to `01:23:45` as in `HH:MM:SS`

I am unsure if I could convert my range K2:K90

How would I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try,

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "H ", ":"), "' ", ":"), ",", "."),UNICHAR(8217)&CHAR(32), ":"), UNICHAR(8221), TEXT(,)), CHAR(34), TEXT(,)))
```

Format the cell as `[hh]:mm:ss` or `[hh]:mm:ss.000` as you like.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I've tried your statement however it just lets me select a cell and after that it doesn't let me do anything. It asks me to put an apostrophe to your formula, Would I need an Additional step ?

Comment: As you can clearly see, the formula works just fine. Suggest you debug it on your own worksheet since *'it doesn't let me do anything'* isn't anywhere near enough to base additional help on.

Comment: @RedayY Which Excel localization/language are you using? This formula is for the english Excel, you probably need to translate it to your localization. Have a look here: [Excel-Translator](https://excel-translator.de/)

Comment: You're right. I apologize. I will try to debug it in my own worksheet. Again thank you for your help :)

Comment: Unfortunatly I am forced to use a German version of Excel, working on debugging it atm.

Comment: There are formula conversion sites available online. I wrote one myself a while back. Maybe try one of those.

Comment: @RedayY If you are on german Excel you don't need to convert the comma into point. German uses comma as decimal separator as default. That's probably why a simple translation won't work here. Try `=ZEITWERT(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(A2; "H "; ":"); "' "; ":");UNIZEICHEN(8217)&ZEICHEN(32); ":"); UNIZEICHEN(8221); TEXT(;)); ZEICHEN(34); TEXT(;)))`

Comment: It worked flawlessly Thank you! One more question. If my field doesn't contain 1H and just 23’ 45,67” would I simply remove the first Substitute ?

Comment: If the H isn't there, leaving the SUBSTITUTE in does nothing since it makes no changes. This should be OK since the seconds have a decimal component and the whole mess shouldn't convert mm:ss to hh:mm which would likely happen if there were no decimal.

Comment: I would assume for simple 45,67" too ?

Comment: @RedayY No, because it doesn't recognize it as time. Use `=WENNFEHLER(ZEITWERT(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(A2; "H "; ":"); "' "; ":");UNIZEICHEN(8217)&ZEICHEN(32); ":"); UNIZEICHEN(8221); TEXT(;)); ZEICHEN(34); TEXT(;)));ZEITWERT("00:00:"&WECHSELN(A2; ZEICHEN(34); TEXT(;))))` for all 3 variations.